Custom Odoo Module Not Showing Up in Apps List
I'm working on customizing the Odoo Sales module on a Windows system, and I have created a custom module. However, when I go to the Apps menu in Odoo, my custom module does not appear in the list.
Here are the steps I've followed:
Using Odoo17
Module Location:
My custom modules are stored in the following directories:
C:\Odoo\server\custom_sales
Odoo Configuration:
I've updated my addons_path in the odoo.conf file to include the following paths:
c:\odoo\server\odoo\addons
C:\Odoo\server\custom_sales
Module Structure:
The custom module contains an init.py, manifest.py, and other necessary files.
The manifest.py file is properly filled out with the required information such as name, version, depends, etc.
Tried Troubleshooting Steps:
Restarted the Odoo service multiple times.
I updated the apps list from the Odoo interface.
Checked the Odoo logs for any errors related to module loading, but found nothing.
Despite all of this, the custom module still doesn’t appear in the Apps list.
Questions:
What could be causing my custom module to not show up in the Apps list?
Are there any additional steps or common issues I might be overlooking?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

If custom_sales is the folder containing the manifest/init you have to add C:\Odoo\server to addons_path. Usually you have an extra folder for custom modules like C:\Odoo\server\custom_addons, which should contain your custom modules.

Ensure there are no spaces after the commas between the paths.
[options]
addons_path = c:/odoo/server/odoo/addons,c:/odoo/server/custom_sales

